# Why does this PHP code produce a different value from this C# code?

Tags: c#, php

PHP CODE:

```
$var1 = (int)395390486;
$var1 <<= 10 & 0xFF;
print($var1);  //outputs 404879857664
```

C# CODE:

```
int var1 = 395390486;
var1 <<= 10 & 0xFF;
Debug.WriteLine(var1); //outputs 1152931840
```

why its doing this ?

Comment: I got same Value 1152931840

Comment: hmm weird wonder if its my version its an older development box

Comment: Which PHP version you are using

Comment: PHP integers are 64 bit, unless aging setup. Y u no explain context?

Comment: php --version
PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.30 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Apr 17 2015 15:01:29)
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies

Comment: PHP default int is 64bit, and C# have 32bit default, use `Int64` in c# then

Comment: I feel like it's something to do with the <<= as opposed to just >> or <<, as I don't have issues with the other bitwise operations, it's just when this <<= comes along that the issue arises.

Comment: The PHP is actually generating the incorrect value, any way to set PHP to 32 bit?

Comment: Note we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I am able to get the same value in PHP by converting to 32 bit with the following function:

```
function intval32bits($value) {
 $value = ($value & 0xFFFFFFFF);
 if ($value & 0x80000000)
 $value = -((~$value & 0xFFFFFFFF) + 1);
 return $value;
}
```